# C# Unity searchbar with inputfield and dropdown, dynamic values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, dropdown, searchbar

This is C#/Unity, the editor is configured correctly.

I got this input field search bar working, with a background dropdown showing dynamic values, but this dropdown only shows on the odd chars (on the first, third... not on the second, fourth...)

Here:

```
//call whenever the input field changes, even OR odd, its working
public void newSearchFieldValueChanged()
{
//read the input field, ok...   
searchText = newSearchField.text;

//return when empty...
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText)) return;

//I need to hide the dropdown   
dropdown.Hide();

//clear its old options
dropdown.ClearOptions();

//this is a dictionary to fill the dropdown options, clear it
dicTemp.Clear();

//add a first empty value
dicTemp.Add("", "0");

//so I run for another dic, that dont change its original values 
for (int i = 0; i < dic.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    //if it contains in its keys the word typed in the search bar...
    if (dic.Keys.ElementAt(i).ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
    {
        //I add it to the cleared dicTemp that will fill the dropdown options   
        dicTemp.Add(dic.Keys.ElementAt(i), dic.Values.ElementAt(i));
    }
}

//fill the dropdown options with the new dicTemp, each time something changes
dropdown.AddOptions(dicTemp.Keys.ToList());

//duh
dropdown.Show();

//keep the focus on input field to continue type (dropdown selected by mouse)
newSearchField.ActivateInputField();
}
```

Again, it works on first letter, and third... but not on second, and fourth, the dropdown DOES NOT SHOW UP (besides the function IS CALLED everytime)...

Comment: Hi @Hogan Sorry, what did you mean?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I did the 
        dropdown.RefreshShownValue();
Thats the equivalent here, I think. Put everywhere, didnt work... thnks

Comment: well... this Refresh is System.Windows.Forms, by the link... but this problem its not a windows forms... its the engine Unity...

Comment: Oh its this guy
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_Dropdown.html

Comment: I know, there´s not much "Description"s in there...

Comment: Here you go... you need a wait a bit between the hid and show -- seems there is a bug in library code -- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1288616/refresh-dropdown-menu-after-reordering-the-items-1.html  Added a delay between Dropdown.Hide() and Dropdown.Show() using WaitForSeconds, it is working now.

Comment: Fantastic. Now I have the dropdown showing up and not showing up, with one second delay lol

Comment: look at this: https://ibb.co/TbNB7GK

Comment: There we have a Debug "EI!" (ignore) "a" I typed... wait that time, 0.9-1.9, the dropdown showed normal. Second type, "ad", the dropdown *VANISHED*, wait 5-6, typed "m" to complete "adm", wait..., the dropdown came normal with "admira" in it

Comment: I've no idea now :/

Comment: thank you, no problem... when I solve this I´ll put in here.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and tried to solve it in 2 days... And I did it now! 
Try not to use *dropdown.Hide();*, but deactivate and activate gameobject with *dropdown.gameObject.SetActive()*. And after activate make *dropdown.Show();*. it works in same frame too, but it blinks every time)))